# Как сформировать массив из выбранных checbox?

Tags: массивы, php, javascript

Делаю так:

```
var i = 0;
        this.type = "specialization";
        $("input:checkbox[name='type\\[\\]']:checked").each(function()
        {
           params_v['specialization'] = $(this).val();
           i++;
        });
```

На стороне PHP планирую получить массив `$specialization = array(0 => 1, 1=> 12, 2=> 34);`
Привычный массив, когда для чекбокса стоит **name="specialization[]"**

Нужно что-то вроде этого: `params_v['specialization'][] = $(this).val();`

Comment: Да, params_v - это объект

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделал так, вроде работает:

```
var spec = [];
        this.type = "specialization";
        $("input:checkbox[name='type\\[\\]']:checked").each(function()
        {
           spec.push($(this).val());
        });

        params_v['specialization'] = spec;
```

Comment: а без переменной spec никак?

Comment: [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) можно заюзать вместо each

Comment: @kolpak, Даже, если map(), то всё равно ж в переменную придётся результат заносить. Разве что, если всю конструкцию не подставлять сразу в параметр для передачи данных.

Comment: @Deonis, пушить сразу в params_v['specialization'] не вариант, верно?

Comment: не понимаю, в чем проблема сделать

    params_v['specialization'] = $(...).map(function(){return this.value}).get()

?